# Compute $\int_{|z|=2}^{}\frac{z^2dz}{z^7+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics

I first find the pole when z=-1. So it should be $z=e^{\frac{2ki\pi+\pi}{7}}$. k=0-6. Then I use Residue Theorem to compute each k? I'm not sure, could anyone give me a hint.

Comment: Yes, use Residue theorem.

Comment: @Surb The result is kind of messy. Bunch of e^pi.

Comment: Two things that will help you avoid tedious multiplication: The product of the differences of the Nth roots of unity is always N times the root that shows up in every difference. The sum of the Nth roots of unity is 0. Of course these are not directly roots of unity, but they would be with a slight "rotation"  of the unit circle i.e. factor out a common phase so you have a $1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I calculated 6 residues and add them together which is very tedious long.  Do you mean the sum is 0?

Comment: Not necessarily. They may be off by alternating minus signs or something else crazy. Use the properties to work out if the minus signs align or not.

Comment: move the contour to infinity ($|z|=R, R \to \infty$) and show integral zero by estimation $|z|^2|dz| =R^3$, $|z^7+1| \ge R^7-1$